# Avoiding linebreak before number

Tags: line-breaking

Is there a way to avoid linebreaks before all numbers without explicitly using the tilde? It would be nice if it worked both for explicit numbers, as in `Sample~1` as well as when a number is implied, as in `Figure~\ref{fig:label}`.

If not, I think I could write a macro in emacs that uses regex to find and fix all the instances of a number or `\ref{}` that should have a tilde.

Comment: have you looked at the `cleveref` package? it might be useful here (for the \ref part of your question)...

Comment: I looked it up, and `cleveref` seems to solve the problem, and more. As far as explicit numbers go, egreg makes some good points about cases where a linebreak before a number is fine. I think I'll use something like `grep ' [0-9]' doc.tex` to review these on a case by case basis, since they don't show up as often as references, at least in my writings.

Answer (score 8):

There's no practical way. One might think to make the digits active and define them as

```
\def1{\ifhmode\unskip~\fi\string1}
```

and similarly for the others. But this would prevent writing innocuos things such as

```
\hspace{1em}
```

and so this is ruled out.

Besides, ties are not always required in front of numbers:

```
as we have seen in cases 1~and~2
```

is better than `cases~1 and~2`.

Conversely one *might* redefine `\ref` so that it does the `\unskip~` operation, but again this is not always the best way of writing by the same reason as before.